# Dynamic Grid.ColumnDefinitions in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need a row with three equal sized columns,

So I declared like,

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now, sometimes, any one of my column may be hidden, in that case the remaining two should get equal width. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change particular `ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` to `0` for hiding corresponding `Grid`'s column and getting the remaining columns equal width, for example :

```cs
//get column definition for the 1st column
var col = myGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0];
//set it's width to 0
col.Width = new GridLength(0);
```